# WebGLRenderingContext - clipping a texture that's already attached

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to find how to clip a texture that is already attached..

For example:

```
var texture = gl.createTexture();

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE); 
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvas);
```

After this, I draw the elements, I want to come in and clip the texture to draw one more time before I clear the context. 
How would I clip a texture that is already bound?

I tried to draw over the texture with black using texSubImage2D but the performance is terrible..

Comment: What do you mean by "clip the texture"?

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean remove part of it. I want to cut out the left half to be precise..   I achieved this with texSubImage2D by adding a black image over the left half, but it's taking a big performance hit doing it that way

Comment: @NicolBolas - the reason I had OpenGL as a tag is because I'm passing the texture to a shader, maybe I can do the clipping there?

Comment: @bushdiver any specific requirements? Image is just binary code. You might work with it in javascript and clip it permanently or you might manipulate it in shader (+pass some uniforms like image current resolution and image desired resolution) and render just part of the picture

Comment: @EntityBlack  I would love to cut it in the shader, but I can't figure out how to do that.. I've tried for days. If I change the resolution in the shader, that's just going to scale it, it's not going to remove the left side of the texture, I don't think..  I can't clip the image with javascript permanently, it's frames from a video, changing 60 frames a second..  So far I'm just drawing the frame twice with texImage2D (it seems faster than texSubImage2D) and the second time drawing the left side black

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "clip a texture". Let's say your texture is 20x10 pixels and your drawing on a quad that's 400x300 pixels. You could mean you want to make the texture 15x10. You'd still see a 400x300 quad it would just have a 15x10 pixel texture stretched across it instead of theo original 20x10. Or maybe you mean you want the quad to be 350x300 instead of 400x300? Or maybe you mean you want to write black to part of the texture so say originally it was 20x10 red but not part of the texture is black. You need be more specific about what you're trying to do.